# pandas: Remove all rows within time interval of another series's time index (i.e. time range exclusion)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
#df1
time
2016-09-12 13:00:00.017    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:03.233    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:10.256    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:19.605    1.0

#df2
time
2016-09-12 13:00:00.017    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:00.233    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:01.016    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:01.505    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:06.017    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:07.233    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:08.256    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:19.705    0.0
```

I want to remove all rows in `df2` that are up to +1 second of the time indices in `df1`, so yielding:

```
#result
time
2016-09-12 13:00:01.505    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:06.017    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:07.233    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:08.256    1.0
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I don't see anything useful for time range exclusions in the API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) which is a new inclusion starting with `0.19.0` and also accepts a tolerance argument to match *+/-* that specified amount of time interval.

```
# Assuming time to be set as the index axis for both df's
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

df2.loc[pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='time', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s')).isnull().any(1)]
```

[image]

Note that default matching is carried out in the *backwards direction*, which means that selection occurs at the last row in the right DataFrame (`df1`) whose `"on"` key (which is `"time"`) is less than or equal to the left's (`df2`) key. Hence, the `tolerance` parameter extends only in this direction (*backward*) resulting in a `-` range of matching.

To have both *forward* as well as *backward* lookups possible, starting with [`0.20.0`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) this can be achieved by making use of `direction='nearest'` argument and including it in the function call. Due to this, the `tolerance` also gets extended both ways resulting in a `+/-` bandwidth range of matching.

Comment: haha..Remembered about @MaxU's comment few days back about it's tolerance param.

Answer (score 5):

Similar idea as @Nickil Maveli, but using [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to build a Boolean indexer:

```
df2 = df2[df1.reindex(df2.index, method='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s')).isnull()]
```

The resulting output:

```
time
2016-09-12 13:00:01.505    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:06.017    1.0
2016-09-12 13:00:07.233    0.0
2016-09-12 13:00:08.256    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to lookup via time indexing (assuming both time columns are indices):

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s')
df2.apply(lambda row: df1[row.name - td:row.name].size > 0, axis=1)
```