# Remove dates from a column that are not within range

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I’ve two imported Panda DataFrames out of Excel (df1 and df2). Df1 represents the dates of replacement consisting out of a column with Dates and a column with Notes (200 rows). Df2 represents the dates when a check was performed (40 rows).

I would like to filter df1 (or generate a new table (df1')), that all dates of df1 which differ less than 5 days with the dates of df2 will be deleted in df1.

As a check is performed, we could say that the component was not replaced within a margin of 10 days.

e.g.

```
df1
22/04/2017
23/04/2017
07/06/2017
20/08/2017

df2 
21/04/2017

df1' 
07/06/2017
20/08/2017
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform datetime subtraction with numpy broadcasting and filter `df1` accordingly.

```
df1
           A
0 2017-04-22
1 2017-04-23
2 2017-07-06
3 2017-08-20

df2 
           A
0 2017-04-21

df1.A = pd.to_datetime(df1.A)    # convert to datetime first  
df2.A = pd.to_datetime(df2.A)
```

```
df1[((df1.values[:, None] - df2.values) / pd.Timedelta(days=1) > 5).all(1)]

           A
2 2017-07-06
3 2017-08-20
```

For your data, this will generate `8000` elements on broadcasted subtraction, which certainly is manageable. Though note for *much* larger data, this results in a memory blowup (a pricey tradeoff for the high performance).

Comment: it partly works ... It does it only till it found one. all others behind are neglected it looks.

Comment: @L.Scheipers Can you provide some sample input which accurately reproduces the problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer now, but what about a `merge_asof` using the `tolerance` argument?

Comment: @pshep123 That would include matches within the tolerance. I believe OP wants those excluded.

Comment: True, but it's a short step to filter out once you have that dataset. Just thinking from a memory perspective given your note.

Comment: @pshep123 Fair point. Okay, I tried this: `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='A', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=5))` but it just echoes `df1` without doing anything. See if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Just tried for the last half hour, couldn't get it to work.  Unless I'm missing something, it should do the trick.  This should work, but doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512442/pandas-remove-all-rows-within-time-interval-of-another-seriess-time-index-i-e.  Or, could be a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206554/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-period

Comment: @pshep123 It really could be a bug. I'm running 0.21, though it seems like it could work on 0.20 (according to the bug Q)